# How to instance 2 different object with only one HTTP request (JSON file)

Tags: java, json, spring, hibernate, rest

I made a database with Java Spring and Hibernate. There is a responsable entity and an account entity and they are linked with OneToOne relation. 
Here is my code :

REST controller :

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/test")
public class test {

    @Autowired
    private final ResponsableDBRepository responsableDBRepository;

    public test(ResponsableDBRepository responsableDBRepository){
        this.responsableDBRepository = responsableDBRepository;
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    ResponseEntity<?> insert(@RequestBody ResponsableEntity responsableEntity) {
        responsableDBRepository.save(responsableEntity);
        return ResponseEntity.accepted().build();
    }
}
```

Responsable entity :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "responsable")
public class ResponsableEntity {

    /**
     * Id of the resident
     */
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    /**
     * First name of the responsable
     */
    @Column(nullable=false)
    private String firstName;

    /**
     * Lst name of the responsable
     */
    @Column(nullable=false)
    private String lastName;

    /**
     * Account id of the responsable
     */
    //@Column(nullable=false)
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "account", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private AccountEntity account;
```

Account entity :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "account")
public class AccountEntity {

    /**
     * Id of the acount
     */
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    /**
     * Username of the acount
     */
    @Column(nullable=false)
    private String username;

    /**
     * Password of the account
     */
    @Column(nullable=false)
    private String password;
```

What I wanted to do is send a POST HTTP request to my controller (/test) and send a JSON to create an account and responsable and link the two in the database

It's a project that I have for the school and It's the first time I am using Spring and Hibernate so I'm not able to say if it's possible or not and how to write the JSON it if it's possible

I already tried a little but nothing works and I don't find my answer on the Internet

Thank you in advance for your answer!

Comment: You may create a wrapper object to wrap both, and send that object as the JSON body.

Comment: Yes, the best way is to create a wrapper DTO (data transfer object) and then work from there on.

Comment: Why does he need a wrapper object? One object already contains the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to send the object in the `Body` part of your `POST request`. Here is an example, try to make a POST request to your url (using `Postman` or any similar tool) with the following `Body (raw/JSON (application/json) )`

```
{
    "firstName": "your_first_name",
    "lastName": "your_last_name",
    "account": 
        {

            "username": "account_username",
            "password": "account_password"
        }

}
```

If you want along with the parent-entity (`ResponsableEntity`) to persist the child entity (`Account`) your models will have to look like this

```
//ResponsableEntity  class
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "id")
private Account account;

//Account class
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "account", cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
private ResponsableEntity  responsableEntity;
```

Please keep in mind that as Willis Blackburn rightly said you will may need to use only cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST instead of all (`ALL` includes the `PERSIST` type).

You can find more about Cascade Types [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/CascadeType.html)

Answer (score 1):

You didn't provide the code for `ResponsableDBRepository` but I assume that somewhere it calls `persist` on the `ResponsableEntity` instance.

If your problem is that the `AccountEntity` you referenced from the `ResponsableEntity` is not being saved, then your issue is probably that you didn't tell Hibernate to cascade the persist operation from `ResponsableDBRepository` to `AccountEntity`. You need to use at least `@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)` but you might want `CascadeType.ALL`.